# Running a basic Qt application in Docker

Tags: c++, windows, qt, docker

I am trying to run a basic console application (*developed in Qt*) in docker for windows. Development environment is windows 10, compiler VC2015, 32bit Application.

It is hello world and idea was to find the issues, before I try to port the actual application.

The code is simplest c++ code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   std::cout<<"Hello world";

   return a.exec();
}
```

The Dockerfile is:

```
# Comment:

#It needs a Microsoft environment to run
FROM microsoft/nanoserver:latest


#Create a folder inside the home folder in the Container Operating System
RUN mkdir -p C:\HelloWorld


#Copy the excutable from this folder to the folder inside the Container 
Operating System.
COPY . /HelloWorld/

#Run the application inside the container operating system.
CMD ["C:\\HelloWorld\\docker_HelloWorld.exe"]
```

My expected end result was a console/shell output of "Hello world". But I get nothing. Can someone point out what is missing?

Thanks.

Comment: GUI application / console ?  their in the different world. do you need a dock GUI Qt app ?

Comment: I have a ready-made GUI application for actual porting. The console is a test with reduced complexity to understand how to port a Qt app to Docker. I do not need a dock GUI Qt app.  If I am able to sort some issues with the GUI application, I will convert that to a console. But that is not the current problem. What I want to understand that how to get this console Qt app running with desired output.

Comment: Did you statically link all the Qt dependencies to your executable?

Comment: Thanks, good point. It is dynamically liked. Let me try linking it statically.

Comment: I still would like to sort it out with dynamic linking, so any help for pointing in the right direction will be welcome.

Comment: @SantoshKumar How did you install QT in docker and which version of qt are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that nanoserver images only supports x64 applications, if possible please build your application as x64 and run it inside the nanoserver with its dependencies.

If not possible to build as x64, then you can use windowsservercore containers to run the x86 applications.

You should copy the dependency assemblies with that application, other wise it will not work.

Comment: Hi Santosh, did you solve your problem? Could you containerize your GUI with dynamic linking ?I have the same issue.